# How to retrieve form object , to the controller if i am not using zend_form to generate the forms

Tags: html, zend-framework, forms, zend-form

I have a form like below in the view :

Here i am not using the zend_form , how can i read the values passed when i am in the controller.

```
 function updateproductsAction(){
    //$request = $this->getRequest();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->getRequest('POST'));
 }
```

above is the controller. I need to read the values passed from the input tags.

thanks in advance

Gayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your controller is "ProductsController" (you didn't give the name), and assuming your form's action="/products/updateproducts" and method="POST" (your form source code is missing), then:

```
function updateproductsAction() {
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        // Assuming input tag "name" values are product_id and quantity:
        $productId = $this->_request->getParam('product_id');
        $quantity = $this->_request->getParam('quantity');
        // etc.. for input tags
    }
}
```

If you were to use Zend_Form (I highly recommend doing so), then the code would be slightly modified as follows:

```
function updateproductsAction() {
    $form = new My_Form_UpdateProducts();
    if ($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
        $productId = $this->_request->getParam('product_id');
        // etc..
    }
}
```

Using Zend_Form allows you to do input validation and filtering and such with minimal effort (i.e. trimming spaces, making all lower/uppercase, ensuring only numeric values were input, etc).

If you were to use method="GET", then isPost() becomes isGet() and getPost() becomes getQuery().